# Select from list linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to get matches from linq query-

```
 public ActionResult TagFilter(TagModel tag) {
        List<CardModel> cardlist = null;
        var cardtaglist = (from u in db.CardTagTables
                           where u.CardTagName == tag.tagName
                           select u).ToList();
        cardlist = (from u in db.CardTables
                    where u.CardID == cardtaglist.Where(e=>e.FKCardTagID==u.CardID)
                    select new CardModel {
                        cardHashCode = tag.tagName,
                        cardDate = u.CardDate,
                        cardFileName = u.CardFileName,
                        cardFilePath = u.CardFilePath,
                        cardID = u.CardID,
                        cardTitle = u.CardTitle
                    }).ToList();
        if (cardlist.Count == 0) {
            return Json(new { success = false });
        }
        else {
            return PartialView("_FunHomePartial", cardlist);
        }

    }
```

Where match of `tag=>tagName` would be from list `cardtaglist`.

I get `Cannot implicitly convert type int to bool` error in line-

```
  where u.CardID == cardtaglist.Where(e=>e.FKCardTagID==u.CardID)
```

How Do I match elements from list `cardtaglist` ?

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do a Join?

Answer (score 1):

How to about replace

```
u.CardID == cardtaglist.Where(e=>e.FKCardTagID==u.CardID)
```

with

```
cardtaglist.Any(e=>e.FKCardTagID==u.CardID)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why you select all `CardTagTable` entity, if you use only `FKCardTagID`!? The best way - to select only required fields:

```
var cardtagIds = (from u in db.CardTagTables
                  where u.CardTagName == tag.tagName
                  select u.FKCardTagID).ToList();
```

About your error, you are traying to compare IQueriable with numeric value. You can use `Contains` method in this case:

```
cardlist = (from u in db.CardTables.Where(u => cardtagIds.Contains(u.CardID));
            select new CardModel {
            ....
```

**Edit**

Also, this query can be optimized:

```
cardlist = (from u in db.CardTables.Where(u => 
                db.CardTagTables
                   .Where(ct => ct.CardTagName == tag.tagName)
                   .Select(ct => ct.FKCardTagID)
                   .Contains(u.CardID))
            select new CardModel {
            ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   var result=cardtaglist.Any(e=>e.FKCardTagID==u.CardID)
```